# VBA for loop error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this loop to take groups of 4 cells in one worksheet and average them into another worksheet. When the one line reads z = z+3 it runs, but if I change it to z = z+4 it doesn't (Runtime error 1004 Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class). Why is this?

```
Dim summary As Worksheet
Set summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim cost As Worksheet
Set cost = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")  

Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
z = 2

For y = 2 To 17

    cost.Cells(y, 3) = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(summary.Cells(4, z), summary.Cells(4, (z + 3)))), 0)
    z = z + 4
Next y
```

Comment: do you have s numeric value that column ? maybe you have a string

Comment: All of the values there are integers

Comment: Do you have values all the way across to `$BQ$4`?

Comment: No, just to $AX$4

Comment: try `Application.Average(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your routine with `z=z+3`, then the final (where y=17) area averaged is `$AX$4:$BA$4`

However, if with `z=z+4`, all those extra cells mean the final area averaged is `$BN$4:$BQ$4`.

As you've stated in your comments that your data only extends to `$AX$4`, once `y` reaches 14 *all* of the cells being averaged are empty, and the function fails.